# To change the Opportunity standard fields

Tags: apex, trigger

while creating a new opportunity, in the edit mode below standard fields are mandatory

[image]

Can we modify these, in edit mode ? I want the opportinity to be bydefault some value say, " N/A", the closed date is " created date + 90 days" and stage is bydefault as " Qualification". We cant even hide those and need to put certain values. Is this possible to achieve this requirement by any code or trigger? Thanks

Comment: You can refer following blog post - http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html by Ray Dehler. It is about "Salesforce URL Hacking to Prepopulate Fields on a Standard Page Layout".

Comment: Hi devendra, plz suggest. while i was able to follow the post for custom object not able to do it for standard objects,

Comment: My button URL is " cs6.salesforce.com/006/e?retURL=%2F006%2Fo";. Now i need to put a text in the opp field say " N/A" But if i am using the api name "{! Opportunity.Name} is not working. Can you plz suggest . So i did is " cs6.salesforce.com/006/e?retURL=%2F006%2Fo&;{! Opportunity.Name} = TEST" which didnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

As far as "not making certain fields required," the answer is no. Without a Close Date, for example, the system wouldn't be able to generate Forecast Reports. For better or worse, you need a value in this field. As you've read, URL "hacks" can pre-populate these values, but you definitely cannot avoid these fields entirely.

Comment: Thanks, I think URL hacking is the only solution that i can use.

Comment: Hello, i am able to use the URL hacking on custom objects and fields which are working But i cant able to make it for standard object like opportunity, Can you plz suggest ?

Comment: My button URL is " https://cs6.salesforce.com/006/e?retURL=%2F006%2Fo". Now i need to put a text in the opp field say " N/A" But if i am using the api name "{! Opportunity.Name} is not working. Can you plz suggest . So i did is " https://cs6.salesforce.com/006/e?retURL=%2F006%2Fo&{! Opportunity.Name} = TEST" which didnt worked.